# Entity Framework "Save As New"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, clone, save-as

I am trying to implement a "Save As New" function in a WPF app built on top of Entity Framework. The idea is

- User loads entity A
- User makes changes to entity A
- User clicks "Save As New" which duplicates entity A into A', A' is saved to the database and A is ultimately not touched.

I have been having a lot of trouble getting this to work. Part of the problem is that my entities are somewhat complicated. E.g., I need to support cases of the form `MyEntity.Property1.CollectionType<EntityItem>` and such. I don't want to be in the situation of calling `Include` on dozens of nested properties. Further, some of the nested entities need to be duplicated, but some are reference data that should not be duplicated. I know exactly which ones these are though.

What I have now looks like the following

```
// Entity is a reference to the entity currently being edited
// Clone is a call to a copy constructor that does the appropriate deep and shallow copies. I.e., entities that need to be duplicated are deep copied and reference data entities are shallow copied.
MyEntity clone = Entity.Clone();

// Reload the current instrument from the database by resetting the context and finding the Entity again.
// This is needed so that when we call SaveChanges, the original entity isn't updated.
Context = new MyEntityContext();
Entity = Context.MyEntities.Find(Entity.Id);

// I have also tried Context.Entry(Entity).Reload(), but this does not reload all the navigation properties (e.g., Entity.Property1.AnotherProperty is not reloaded).

Context.MyEntities.Add(clone);
Context.SaveChanges();
```

The problem with the above code is that it duplicates everything, even the properties that have been shallow copied. I understand why this is happening, but I can't figure out the best way to save duplicate some data but not others.

What should I be doing here to get this functionality to work in Entity Framework?

Comment: Is your method shallow copying the original's `Id`?

Comment: @Shoe In the `Clone` method anything that I want inserted as a new entity I set the `Id` property to 0. That's the easiest way I've found to get EF to treat that entity as new. Everything that I want not duplicated gets the same `Id`.

Comment: Try opening your context before cloning. You also shouldn't need to find the original if your intent is to save a new entity.

Comment: @Shoe When you say opening context before cloning, do you mean move the `Context = new MyEntityContext();` line above the `Clone()` line?